# CiviPledge "Next Payment Date" automatically set to Jan. 1, 1970

Tags: civicontribute, civipledge

When I enable pledges on a contribution form, CiviCRM processes the first payment properly, and records the correct "pledge made date".

However, it records the "next payment date/payments start" as Jan. 1, 1970, and subsequent payments in their proper increments (weekly, monthly, etc.) on the proper day of that period.

Obviously, this error doesn't apply to pledges entered manually.

I am running Wordpress 4.6.1 with CiviCRM 4.7.12. Any ideas as to what's behind the timewarp back to the 1970s?

Answer (score 1):

After updating to CiviCRM 4.7.14, this issue has disappeared. I am unable to replicate it on the CiviCRM Wordpress demo as well, so I think it must have just been an issue with my version being out of date.

Comment: Yes - you stumbled on CRM-19153 (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19153), which was fixed in CiviCRM 4.7.14.